# Received a settlement check for lost wages, what kind of taxes apply?

Tags: united-states, taxes, lawsuit-settlement

I received a settlement check from a company for lost wages, and was given a 1099 for 2019. The check itself was for about $2.3k USD, and included a breakdown that didn't make sense to me and showed on the 1099 for ~$750 USD for the wages section. The actual check is for about ~$1900.

I've never received a settlement, but the total amounts here don't make sense to me. The lawyer's fee was taken out of the overall settlement, and it showed that taxes for federal/state etc. were removed, but the math doesn't really add up.

If the 1099 shows the $750 as wages, is my money already taxed? Is it just the amount of wages lost that was taxed and the rest is emotional damages (or whatever)? I wasn't a main plaintiff (class action), so I don't have a lawyer to relate to on this.

**What sort of taxes should I look for on a lost wages and more on a settlement check?**

My goal is to not owe next year (or owe more than I otherwise would have due to this).

Comment: Does the 1099 show anything for 'Federal Income Tax Withheld' (Box 4)? Is the non-wage portion identified anywhere as punitive damages?

Comment: @HartCO No, it just shows ~$750 in the top box. I'll take a picture (and omit some items) when I get home.

Comment: You may want to recheck the settlement notice to see how claims were going to be processed and paid. Was this settlement based on actual lost wages owed to you?

Comment: @pboss3010 It was a settlement for unpaid overtime and breaks not being paid by the company, plus additions for not doing so. None of the tax matters were in the settlement notice.